# Theoretically, can I count something several times?

Tags: countability

[image][image]As a picture above shows, we say 'there are three spotlights' even though the three spotlights meet in one point and make an one circle. Isn't only 'there is one spotlight' correct?

Comment: I don't get the question...

Comment: It's simple, imagine shadows of people are in the same place.

Comment: A spot of light and a spotlight are different things. If five spotlights are directed to make one spot of light, it would be an error to say 'there is one spotlight'.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary says a spotlight means a circle of strong light that comes from a lamp whose beam can be directed:

Comment: Nevertheless, it would be awkward and ambiguous to call a merged circle of light from several sources, themselves spotlights (or spotlamps)  'one spotlight'.

Comment: But 'one spotlight' is said more

Comment: @user126927 - "is said more" - how do you know that?

Comment: The three spots of light are unlikely to coincide *exactly*, but together they make a *pool* of light. Similarly if you throw three buckets of water onto the same place, there is only one pool of water, not three. But there are still three spotlights, and three buckets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, this is a tricky question. Those lamps at the top are called *spotlights*, because the pattern of light they throw produces a focused, circular spot. And there are three of them, so there are *three spotlights*.

But also, *a spotlight* is a name used for the actual result, the focused spot of light highlighting someone or something. It's such an important feature of theatre that it can be called ***the** spotlight*, and that term is used figuratively in English (*in the spotlight*) to talk about someone who has everyone's attention focused on them.

And when you have that (one) spotlight on stage, nobody's really thinking about how many actual lamps are being used to create that effect. That's a technical consideration. So really, it depends on exactly what you're talking about, the lamps or the spot of light itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would call the three lights *spotlights* and the single illuminated place a *spot*. The word *spot* is also used sometimes as abbreviation for *spotlight*, but it would be clear from context what is meant.